# LINQ Query for Unsanitized Data

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a `List<MyData>` where `MyData` contains a `Location` field.

This field is a string, and is normally in "City, State" format but sometimes will come in as "Unknown".

There is another field, `DateField`.

I need to return a list of `MyData` objects grouped by the year in `DateField`, grouped by the *state* portion of `Location`, if that exists.  If it comes in as "Unknown" then I need to ignore that.

My thoughts are use `RemoveAll()` on the `List<>` where `(r => r.Location.Split(",").Length == 0)`, or if it doesn't include a comma at all.

Then I will have sanitized data.

That leaves me with two questions:

1. Is this the correct approach, or can I just handle it all with one LINQ query?
2. What should this LINQ query look like?  I am looking state totals by a year specific year, which is passed into the API as an `int`.

I hope that comes across clear.  Thanks.

Comment: Please, share some example data and `MyData` class as well

Comment: can you explain what you need as output

Comment: @Muhammad I need `Count()` grouped by `MyData.State` for a given `Year` that is passed in as an `int` param.

Comment: Yes I have answered it according to understanding. Have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can try to do the following. Filter the data with known `Location` first, then group it by two keys, year from `DateField` and `State`, and finally select a result

```cs
var data = new List<MyData>();
var result = data.Where(l => l.Location != "Unknown")
    .GroupBy(d => new { d.DateField.Year, State = d.Location.Split(",").LastOrDefault() })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        g.Key.Year,
        g.Key.State,
        Total = g.Count()
    });
```

Comment: That looks good, I tried something similar and it seems to work (I have to also exclude anything without a comma, because `Location` is sometimes international with no comma like "Berlin Germany" which also needs to be ignored.  How do you return anonymous types as JSON from .Net Core 3.1 API?

Comment: @Patrick you can just pass the result to `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` method (if you are using `Newtonsoft.Json`)

Comment: As for the `System.Text.Json` api, I'm not sure that it supports anonymous  types fro now

Answer (score 1):

This query removes an state with `unkonwn` and also group on year of datefield ans state part of location

```
var mydata = new List<MyData>();
mydata.Where(x => x.Location != "Unknown")
       .GroupBy(x => new { x.DateField.Date.Year, State = 
                x.Location.Split(',').LastOrDefault() })
       .Select(x => new {

                    Year = x.Key.Year,
                    Count = x.Count()
              });
```

Comment: Thanks this is the correct answer, Pavel got it to it first but I've upvoted accordingly.